# How can I improve my program in VB.NET 2013 for better performance?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, performance

I wrote a program with 6 threads, in my CORE I7 goes fine but when I run it in a CELERON does not work. It seems that threads stop working.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    trd = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
    barreras_trd = New Thread(AddressOf barreras)
    sensores_trd = New Thread(AddressOf sensores)
    convierte_trd = New Thread(AddressOf convierte)
    emite_tiquet_trd = New Thread(AddressOf tiquet)
    actualiza_trd = New Thread(AddressOf actualiza_grilla)

    trd.IsBackground = True
    barreras_trd.IsBackground = True
    sensores_trd.IsBackground = True
    convierte_trd.IsBackground = True
    emite_tiquet_trd.IsBackground = True
    actualiza_trd.IsBackground = True

    trd.Start()
    barreras_trd.Start()
    sensores_trd.Start()
    convierte_trd.Start()
    emite_tiquet_trd.Start()
    actualiza_trd.Start()

    Me.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

    'Select the last row.
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Selected = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` is a very bad practice, make a research on how to use threads in vb.net and how to update GUI from another thread. you can start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289496(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Don't use a separate thread for each threat.  Just use one thread for threats and loop through each one and update it somehow.  Without seeing your code that's about as helpful as we can get!

Comment: You probably have synchronization deadlock issues, but not in the part of the code you posted. Not answerable this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since we've no idea what your threaded methods do, we can't offer much, but you could at least simplify to one of these:

**Option 1**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True

    ' Runs all in parallel (give or take the scheduler and duration)
    Task.Run(Sub() ThreadTask())
    Task.Run(Sub() barreras())
    Task.Run(Sub() sensores())
    Task.Run(Sub() convierte())
    Task.Run(Sub() tiquet())
    Task.Run(Sub() actualiza_grilla())

    Me.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

    'Select the last row.
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Selected = True
End Sub
```

**Option 2**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True

    Task.Run(Sub() AllThreads())

    Me.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

    'Select the last row.
    Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Selected = True
End Sub

Sub AllThreads()
    ' Runs each in series
    ThreadTask()
    barreras()
    sensores()
    convierte()
    tiquet()
    actualiza_grilla()
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It guide me where I must go. The solution is TPL. (task parallel library)